# Jquery function working in chrome and edge but IE throws an error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML code which uses the jquery map function to import the members of an array inside of an array, into the root array (hopefully that makes sense).

I have the following:

```
var data = $.makeArray(object.data);
data = data.map((v) => $.extend(v, v.Files));
```

This works perfectly fine in Chrome and in Edge, but Internet Explorer says that this is javascript error. Also in my IDE (PHPStorm) it highlights `(v)` and `=>` as being the issue.

I can't see what's wrong with this and don't understand why the IDE and IE are showing it an error when in Chrome and Edge its fine.

Comment: Which version of IE? It could be due to the use of `map()` in ECMA6, or even the arrow function

Comment: I'm using IE11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of IE the issue will wither be your use of `map()`, which is unsupported in <IE11, and has patchy support at best in IE11 itself, or it will be due to the arrow function which has no support in IE at all.

To work around both issues, you can use jQuery's `$.map()` instead of the native ECMA6 `map()` and use a regular anonymous function for the handler:

```
var data = $.makeArray(object.data);
data = $.map(data, function(v) {
  return $.extend(v, v.Files));
});
```

Comment: Cheers, IE must be worst part of web development :(

Comment: Absolutely without doubt. The worst thing is that Edge is no better either.